# STM32 PWM only works correctly when I leave in two unused variables: StartUpCounter and HSEStatus

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, gcc

I'm using the stm32f3discovery board to try and generate the signal for a ws2812 light strip.

I've got `src/system_stm32f30x.c`, which I copied from the StdPeriph examples.  I'm currently using the internal HSI, and the clock speed is 48MHz.

I'm using gcc-arm-none-eabi-4_8-2014q3 to compile.

If I leave `src/system_stm32f30x.c` as is, I get compiler warnings about unused variables, HSEStatus, and StartUpCounter, but my program works correctly.  If I rename the variables to test1 and test2, it still works as expected, so it appears that it doesn't matter what the variables are named, it just matters that they are taking up memory (I guess).

However, if I comment these variables in order to get rid of the warning, my program no longer works correctly.  The first pulse of the PWM signal is either grossly too short, or way to long.  It causes the first LED on my strip to flash erratically (though the rest of the LEDs are fine).

My code is here: https://github.com/synic/neoclock/tree/stm32f303

What could it be?

Comment: That typically means you have something writing to the wrong memory locations, and those unused variables serve as a buffer to protect.  You can try setting them to magic values and checking later to see if they have been changed.  (iirc, the `_IO` macro includes `volatile`).

Comment: I think something is more fundamentally wrong with your build.  If the variables are unused, it should be because their use is excluded by the preprocessor directives, in which case looking at the directives in your source they shouldn't even be seen to generate a warning.  When I get that suspicious I start putting #warning (or even intentional syntax errors) in various places in the code to absolutely prove what is and isn't being processed by the compiler.

Comment: I've done a `watch -l StartUpCounter` in gdb, and after that it basically breaks at every line in `setup_gpio`.  Does this mean that memory is accessed every time?

Comment: It may just mean gdb is confused.  If those are stack variables (as at first glance it appears they should be, if _IO is only volatile and not static) then the memory will only belong to them when inside the function, and may have other legitimate uses at other times.  If they are globals, then it suggests some sort of memory corruption.  Can you arm-whatever-objdump -d the file and post the implementation of the initialization function where they appear in your git?

Comment: @ChrisStratton - The only definitions of `__IO` I can find in the STM32F3-DISCOVERY source is `#define __IO volatile`. They are on the stack. Now that the code on github is supposed to be the same as being compiled, it is no longer not clear what the problem is. Have the "compiler warnings about unused variables" gone away? If the variables are commented out, does it change the PWM frequency. I think the OP needs to be clear.

Comment: @gbulmer: The file as it is on github now is what I'm referring to.  If I comment the two variables, the first pulse of the PWM signal is off (too short, too long, etc).  If I do not comment them, I get the compiler warnings, but the program works fine.  I'm mostly trying to figure out why... I can live with the warnings, but I feel like I'm missing something bigger here.

Comment: Yo are missing the point. In the original file, either the compiler must *never ever, under any syntactically valid circumstances* see those variables; the entire block is `#if defined` out. **Or** the compiler is seeing that code, and your assertion that the *HSI oscillator is used* is **incorrect**. That may explain everything else. By changing the code it has become *harder* to diagnose your problem. You should not need to touch that code at all. I would expect the manufacturer has tested it. The problem is most likely in the build or your other code. However, I give up. Good luck.

Comment: @gbulmer: I'm guessing you haven't refreshed, as I keep saying, those variables are defined at the top of the function.  I don't know why you keep saying they aren't, but obviously I've rubbed you the wrong way somehow.  Thanks for your help anyway.  Also, they are project template files, that you are supposed to edit if you want to change the clock frequency.  Furthermore, I don't have an HSE, so HSI is really the only option.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: https://gist.github.com/synic/dc8df870bf422e888711

Comment: I understand that HSI is the option you'd like to use. However, one point is the error messages that you were getting can *only* be explained by the compiler seeing the variables where they were. It could *only* see that code if `PLL_SOURCE_HSI` is **NOT** defined. Further, that code is likely tested, so changing the code (ignoring the change to a PPL multiplier) doesn't seem to improve anything. Secondly, the comment at the start of system_stm32f30x.c says "The STM32F0xx is configured to run at 48 MHz", so there seems to be no reason to change it!

Comment: I'm not getting ANY error messages.  Only compiler warnings that StartUpCounter and HSEStatus are unused.  The error occurs in the PWM output only, and only when those variables are commented.  I only commented those variables because of the warning, and then later noticed it had caused a problem.  It took me quite a while to narrow the problem down to those two variables.  If I comment them, the program doesn't work, and if I don't, it does.  Perhaps I shouldn't have edited the file.  However, I did, and now I'm wondering why it caused a problem.  If the answer is "because", that's ok.

Comment: There is clearly a problem if commenting out two unused variables causes a programs behaviour to change. That was established earlier. If you put the variables back to where they were (revert to the manufacturers file), then they should *never* be seen by the compiler, and the HSI oscillator should be used at 48MHz. An error/warning messages about them tell us VERY useful stuff. If there is a warning/error you still may have a bug. However, the bug is likely your code, not in ST's system_stm32f30x.c. So, once the original ST code is running, with no warnings, is there any problem?

Comment: You misunderstand, where they are now (at the top of the function) is where they were originally.  I moved them inside the define trying to figure out what was wrong.  It was my bad to upload the wrong version of the file and then post it here.

Comment: Okay, that is clearer, thank you. So did the system_stm32f30x.c file come from one of the STM32F3-Discovery Peripheral_Examples, e.g. TIM_Asymetric or something? HSI is already running, and ST's code sets the PLL to give 48MHz. __IO is `volatile`. Those variables are on the stack. The function doesn't call any other functions. AFAICT it doesn't do any pointer arithmetic. So it isn't obvious how it could break anything called *after* it returns, unless it breaks the oscillator settings. So, how do you measure the PWM signal for the LEDs? How do you test the oscillator is right? Oscilloscope?

Comment: You code won't build since it's missing a lot of the header files, but it looks like declaring those volatile stack variables has the effect of **zero initializing** some memory a bit beyond two function calls down the stack.  Your gpio initialization routine would be at the same stack depth.  I can't see any obvious place where you are assuming the initial value of a stack variable, but if you are that could be an explanation.  Granted, the memory was supposed to be zero-initialized just before this.  I'm curious though what happens if you give these "unused" variables non-zero values.

Comment: @ChrisStratton:  I'll try that when I get home.  If you want to try building the code, I've just linked `STM32F30x_DSP_StdPeriph_Lib_V1.1.0/Libraries` to the periphlib inside the source directory.  @gbulmer: yes, I am using an oscilloscope.

Answer (score 2):

Is `PLL_SOURCE_HSI` `#defined` in your code?

In `system_stm32f30x.c`, it looks like `HSEStatus`, and `StartUpCounter` should *never* be defined **IFF** your code is using the HSI oscillator.

Their definition is in the code:

```
#if defined (PLL_SOURCE_HSI)
...
#else
#if defined (PLL_SOURCE_HSE)
__IO uint32_t StartUpCounter = 0, HSEStatus = 0;
```

So, it appears that something is undefine-ing `PLL_SOURCE_HSI`, and hence allowing `StartUpCounter` and `HSEStatus` to be defined.

I can't see anything in the source file `src/system_stm32f30x.c` to cause that.

So either:

1. the `src/system_stm32f30x.c` file at github is not the one being used in your build, or
2. your build is somehow causing `PLL_SOURCE_HSI` to become undefined
   and `PLL_SOURCE_HSE` to be defined (which seems unlikely to get both), or
3. the include file `stm32f30x.h` contains a syntax error which is
   causing some of this.

1 and 3 seem more likely.

Those two variables are local to SetSysClock. So their names can be safely changed.

Commenting out their definition should cause the compile of that source file to fail.

If the build is producing a program, then `src/system_stm32f30x.c` is not part of the program, or an old object is being used, or their is an inconsistency in the question.

If the HSI oscillator is being used in one case, and not in another, it is plausible that the PWM period is inconsistent.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I had the wrong file committed (some of my earlier debugging attempts).  It is now back to what it was before.  Those two variables were defined at the beginning of the SetSysClock function.

Comment: Someone in the stm32 channel suggested I try using `__attribute__((aligned(4)))` on the struct that contains `dma_buffer`, however that seems to have produced no changes.

Comment: @synic - So, when you comment out those two variables, does the code compile?

Comment: Yup, it compiles, but I think that's because where they are accessed is enclosed in #defines.  I ma using `PLL_SOURCE_HSI`, so the code later in the function that references those two variables is never compiled.

Comment: @synic - There definition, ` __IO uint32_t StartUpCounter = 0, HSEStatus = 0;` is *not* " enclosed in #defines". There definitions, and all the code that uses them are enclosed in `#if defined (PLL_SOURCE_HSI)
...
#else
#if defined (PLL_SOURCE_HSE)` as I wrote in my answer. `#define` and `#if defined(...)` are very different. So, if you do not 'comment them out' have the compiler warnings gone away?

Comment: Sorry, I had updated the code.  Those two defines are at the very top of the function, outside any preproccessor directives.

Comment: The code that reads and writes to them is enclosed in the preprocessor directives.  So commenting/uncommenting them has no effect on whether or not the program compiles (if `PLL_SOURCE_HSI` is set, which it is),

Comment: @synic - why are you changing code supplied by the manufacturer? That seems to be a fundamentally bad idea. You now have code which is different from a distribution for no apparent reason. It appears that  either the original code is correct, or you have made a change, but have no way to test it.

Comment: Changing that file is the only way to change the clock frequency.  I will leave the variables there, it just kinda bugs me that I'm getting compiler warnings.  OCD, yes, but at this point I want to know *why* it does what it does.

Comment: @synic - The program seems broken. Give up on changing the clock multiplier until the rest has started to behave properly. Good luck.

Comment: it may be worth writing known values (e.g. 0x12345678 and 0xaa55aa55) to these variables and then with the debugger break the code at various points to see when these values change. Seeing when (and sometimes seeing what they change to) often gives hints to what's going on. If your debugger supports break-on-memory-access you can use that to halt the code at the exact moment that the memory is accessed.